# KitKat upgrade for HTC Desire 616

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, htc

I can't upgrade my HTC Desire 616 to KitKat 4.4.4 but my phone is absolutely capable of running this update! How can I update it?

Comment: More information needed for this post. Is it a system update or you're trying to flash a custom Rom?

Answer (score -1):

If you are rooted and modified system files you cannot upgrade through official OTA anymore. You can always flash a custom ROM though

Comment: That may be true, but can you explain how did you reach this conclusion? A source would be very nice to link here.

Comment: If the system files are modified the OTA installer doesn't "recognize" the ROM. There's plenty of people who have had this problem. Just Google it.

Comment: No, I don't have time to Google nor would a frustrated user would have. Please add more info as explanation and source since the answer isn't any worth right now because of no evidence to back the claim.